# svg tap highlight prevention on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, html, webkit

I just wanna prevent the tap highlight while touching any object in my iphone webkit

I used the below one over a canvas

```
      .transparent{
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

        }
```

which worked perfectly but the same doesn't work with svg is there any other way to prevent this highlight.

I also tried

```
    .transparent{
          -webkit-highlight: none;
        }
```

any help plz...

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the stylesheet:

```
a {-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
```